# Plotting 3 variables on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset about apple store apps, I wanna plot a graph (heat map, scatter, or bar) to show app_name (x), app_reviews (y)"will be used also to show the size of point, the larger the more reviews", and color each point with app_category

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeFOO.png)

Comment: You can check `matplotlib` (as per your question tags) docs, where you can find multiple examples and great documentation: [heat map](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html), [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) or [bar plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please share the code you managed to write so far? (if possible, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can also look into dimensional reduction techniques (PCA, T-sne, Umap) to plot in reduced to 2dims space.

Comment: I have to plot using 3 variables for "multivariant exploration"

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.